# Running an integration test again a web api using Auth0 authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

I've got an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API which I'm now creating integration tests for using XUnit. The API, however, uses Auth0 as the authentication server. All its controller actions are protected with the [Authorize] decorator.

For now, I simply wanted to add a hard-coded access token to the tests - which I can obtain from the Auth0 web site - so that the tests can successfully authenticate against the API and do its thing. I do this exact same thing all the time with Postman to test my API and it works great.

So this is the code I have in my one test class:

```
public class FileControllerTests
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly TestServer _server;

    public FileControllerTests()
    {
        _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
        _client = _server.CreateClient();
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("GET")]
    public async Task TestFilesAsync(string method)
    {
        // Arrange
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(method), "/api/files");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", ACCESS_TOKEN);

        // Act
        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

When I run this test, I get this error:

> **System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).**

However, if I remove the [Authorize] decorator from the API's controller, then the test works and passes. Any ideas?

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2017 (version 15.9.4)

EDIT: Instead of:

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

I've also tried

```
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

But it made no difference.

Comment: show startup and where auth is configured.

Comment: Take a look at the `Testing the Integration` section in this Auth0 article https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/